# jQuery UI Autocomplete - Trigger an event without select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have this autocomplete in a input box and all is working fine:

```
$(function() {
    $("#customer").autocomplete({   
      minLength: 1,  
      source: function(request, response) {
          $.getJSON('url.php', { 'string': request.term }, function(data) {
              if(data) { 
                  var clienti = data.error ? [] : $.map(data, function(customer) {
                      return { 
                        label: customer.fullname,
                        array: customer
                    };
                  });
                  response(clienti);
              } 
          });
      },      
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#description").val(ui.item.array.description);         
      } 
    })
});
```

I want to call (trigger) the same autocomplete function ON LOADING another page, but WITHOUT select an item! (simply by pass data to Ajax).

If i use $("#customer").autocomplete("search") all is working BUT i need to select the ITEM to view the $("#description").val !
$("#customer").val is loaded by PHP on page load.

How could i do?
Thank you.

Comment: You ever heard of `$( document ).ready(){`?

Comment: yes of course, but I probably badly explained: could i use a jquery autocomplete response function into another page for example with the select disabled ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain more clearly.

Comment: Ok: i got autocomplete on a input, and when i type something autocomplete make an ajax call and give me a response. After that i save $_POST['customer'] into a db. When i call another page, i read from db $customer value on loading. NOW could i call $("#customer").autocomplete for set $("#description").val (see the function) ? In this case i save a lot of coding..

Comment: You're confusing everything with this other page stuff, then leaving off in the next sentence which page you're talking about. You cannot directly manipulate another page via ajax. But if you do an ajax request that puts something in a db, and then in another page do an ajax request to read the db then you can read what was put in the db from the previous page. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: not really: i make a php call to db for read $customer (and other stuff) and then i want to use the autocomplete ajax call for read $customer[$description] and a lot of other stuff. I don't want to copy ajax reading call to another php reading call.. for save coding.. if it is possibile :)

Comment: You can't use one ajax call to effect two different tabs...each one has to do its own ajax calls...